# F# Pattern matching with an argument

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

This is probably simple but can someone explain why the following pattern matching is not sensible? It says other rules e.g. 1, 0, _ will never be matched.

```
let matchTest(n : int) = 
    let ran = new Random()
    let i = ran.Next(0, 2)
    match i with
    | n -> printfn "%i" n
    | 1 -> printfn "1"
    | 0 -> printfn "0"
    | _ -> printfn "impossible"
```

The same thing for this:

```
let matchTest(n : int) = 
    let ran = new Random()
    let i = ran.Next(0, 2)
    let m = n
    match i with
    | m -> printfn "%i" m
    | 1 -> printfn "1"
    | 0 -> printfn "0"
    | _ -> printfn "impossible"
```

So why can't it match `n` or `m` directly here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `n` in the first example is a place-holder symbol which gets populated if the match succeeds. It's the same as writing:

```
let matchTest(n : int) = 
    let ran = new Random()
    let i = ran.Next(0, 2)
    match i with
    | x -> printfn "%i" x
    | 1 -> printfn "1"
    | 0 -> printfn "0"
    | _ -> printfn "impossible"
```

The symbol `x` is populated with the value of `i` if the match succeeds, and is then available to use on the right hand side of `->`. This match *always* succeeds, which explains why the rest of the match cases are unreachable.

In your case, it just so happens that you've named the match variable `n`, which is the same name as the input argument.

It's not the same value, though. Instead, what happens is that a new value, *also called* `n` is being created, and the previous `n` is no longer accessible.

This is a language feature called **shadowing**.

You can also see it outside of pattern matching:

```
let foo n =
    let n = 1
    n
```

Example usage:

```
> foo 42;;
val it : int = 1
> foo 1337;;
val it : int = 1
```

As you can see, the let-bound `n` shadows the input argument `n`.

The second example in the OP, where you match on `n` is a variation on the first, so the same explanation applies.

Comment: hmmmm. is this really shadowing? and not actually scoping? since the pattern is an lambda? or is my other answer then wrong? or is shadowing and scope/lambda same? and last but not least: am I confused?

Comment: @HelgeReneUrholm I agree that shadowing is the definitely the correct term. While scope has a role to play and you are not wholly incorrect, it is misleading to suggest that the key aspect is that there is nesting going on - remember (search for Light Syntax) in F# every line implicitly has an `in` connecting it to the next expression

Answer (score 3):

Your first pattern

```
| m ->
```

has a variable `m` which can match any value. You are thinking that the `m` in

```
let m = n
```

is the same `m` variable and it is not.

So the remaining patterns will never get matched because the first pattern matches all of the input.

You need a [when clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233242.aspx), see [guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science))

```
| m when m = n ->
```

Comment: I knew how to fix it but didn't understand why it can't be like this. I think I didn't fully understand  what happens behind the pattern matching, thought it was simple comparison which its not.

Answer (score 3):

If you rewrite your match as about the following you maybe understands it better:

```
let matchTest(n : int) = 
    let ran = new Random()
    ran.Next(0, 2)
    |> function
       | n -> printfn "%i" n
       | 1 -> printfn "1"
       | 0 -> printfn "0"
       | _ -> printfn "impossible"
```

The point is that the match (or function) takes an param, but everything inside is locally declared as your code is initially written. No closure are applied at this point for (outside) n.

The part

```
| pattern ->
```

pattern is in fact a 'new local variable' in match/function scope (i.e. an lambda) and **NOT** the same as n outside.

You then need to apply the guard clause for this "newly created variable":

```
| pattern when pattern = n -> printfn "%i" n
```

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233242.aspx

Or the exhaustive explanations with examples and what you never knew you should learn (in best meaning!) at http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/match-expression/

And yes, match expressions might be confusing at first. It was for me at least.